# Pandas Inverting Cumulative Count

Tags: pandas, cumulative-sum

I am given a dataframe with *cumulative* count data. An example is generated as follows (feel free to skip:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

cols = ['Start', 'End', 'Count']
data = np.array([
    '2020-1-1', '2020-1-2',      4,
    '2020-1-1', '2020-1-3',      6,
    '2020-1-1', '2020-1-4',      8,
    '2020-2-1', '2020-2-2',      3,
    '2020-2-1', '2020-2-3',      4,
    '2020-2-1', '2020-2-4',      4])
data = data.reshape((6,3))
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols, data=data)
df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Start)
df['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df.End)
```

This gives the following dataframe:

```
Start        End      Count
2020-1-1 2020-1-2      4
2020-1-1 2020-1-3      6
2020-1-1 2020-1-4      8
2020-2-1 2020-2-2      3
2020-2-1 2020-2-3      4
2020-2-1 2020-2-4      4
```

The counts are cumulative (accumulation starts on Start) and I want to undo the accumulation to get (note the change in dates):

```
Start        End      Count
2020-1-1 2020-1-2      4
2020-1-2 2020-1-3      2
2020-1-3 2020-1-4      2
2020-2-1 2020-2-2      3
2020-2-2 2020-2-3      1
2020-2-3 2020-2-4      0
```

I would like to do this for grouped variables. This can be done naively by:

```
lst = []
for start, data in df.groupby(['Start', 'grouping_variable']):
    data = data.sort_values('End')
    diff = data.Count.diff()
    diff.iloc[0] = data.Count.iloc[0]
    start_dates = [data.Start.iloc[0]] + list(data.end[:-1].values)
    data = data.assign(Start=start_dates,
                       Count=diff)

    lst.append(data)


df = pd.concat(lst)
```

This does not feel "right", "pythonic" or "clean" in any way. Is there a better way? Perhaps Pandas has a specific method to do this?

Comment: @Datanovice, no

Comment: @Datanovice the accumulation starts on Start, I was not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, we can use `cumcount` with a boolean to capture each unique start date group then apply a `np.where` operation using `shift` to each group.

```
import numpy as np
#df['Count'] = df['Count'].astype(int)

s = df.groupby(['Start']).cumcount() == 0
df['Count'] = np.where(s,df['Count'],df['Count'] - df['Count'].shift())
df['Start'] = np.where(s, df['Start'], df['End'].shift(1))
    

print(df)
       Start        End  Count
0 2020-01-01 2020-01-02    4.0
1 2020-01-02 2020-01-03    2.0
2 2020-01-03 2020-01-04    2.0
3 2020-02-01 2020-02-02    3.0
4 2020-02-02 2020-02-03    1.0
5 2020-02-03 2020-02-04    0.0
```

Comment: Looks very sleek! But you do not change the dates, I imagine you'd do that using a shift for the dates?

Comment: @YairDaon see edit, first solution was pretty terrible!